# Do I need to repeat the class attribute for each source inside a picture element? (HTML5)

Tags: html, image

I'm in the process of converting our images to webp, which means I need to use the 'picture' tag instead of 'img', as picture allows for a fallback to png formats for devices and browsers that don't support webp.

Anyway, I have an img that looks like this:

```
<img class="usp-pics pic1" src="/images/example.png" alt="" title="">
```

So, converting this to webp with the ability to fallback to png would look something like this:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="/images/example.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source srcset="/images/example.png" type="image/png">
    <img class="usp-pics pic1" src="/images/example.png" alt="" title="">
</picture>
```

If a browser reads the above code and takes the first webp image, will it also apply the classes, alt & title tags attached to the img element or do I need to repeat them for each source, or add them to the parent picture tag?

I've tried to look this up but I can't find an answer. Maybe because it's obvious or maybe because I'm using the wrong words to describe the issue. Sorry if this has already been covered somewhere.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[**Acccording to MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) the `<picture>` element simply takes the content of the `<source>` and puts it inside the space defined by the `<img>` tag:

> The browser will consider each child `<source>` element and choose the best match among them. If no matches are found—or the browser doesn't support the `<picture>` element—the URL of the `<img>` element's src attribute is selected. **The selected image is then presented in the space occupied by the `<img>` element**.

*(My emphesis)*

Therefore, I would expect that the classes on the `<img>` tag would still appear to the end user, regardless of which (or any) `<source>` material is used.

## My Testing:

But I had not checked this. So I decided to run a few tests with image types (PNG / JPG / Webp) and `<picture>` elements:

```css
.one {
  border: 3px solid #f00;
}
.two {
  border: 3px solid #0f0;
}
.thr {
  border: 3px solid #00f;
}
.fou {
  /* Picture Element */
  border: 3px solid #333;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<picture class='fou'>
    <source srcset="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.webp" type="image/webp" class='thr'>
    <source srcset="https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/img/art-direction.png" type="image/png" class='two'>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/163016/crash-test-collision-60-km-h-distraction-163016.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="" title="" class='one'>
</picture>
```

From the above example, and from editing it and playing with it by

- Rearranging the `<source>` materials.

It can be easily found that:

- The `<source>` elements are **NOT** hidden on the page,but do not contain the graphical content.
- Regardless of the `<source>` used, the `<img>` element is always the element that contains the picture graphic (sometimes called an image (*WTF?*) ) .
- The `<picture>` container object always exists but is a container such as `<figure>` in HTML5. It should not be given CSS styling intended for contents such as `<img>`.

## Conclusion:

The code above (and its fiddles and edits) shows that all elements are present in the HTML, but the only one that *is* the image is the `<img>` element.

Therefore, you should not be applying any styling or CSS whatsoever to `<source>` elements and only container stylings should be applied to `<picture>` elements.

## You Asked:

> Do I need to repeat the class attribute for each source inside a picture element?

## The Answer:

The answer is **NO**. You should style the `<img>` element *ONLY*.

Example:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="/images/example.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source srcset="/images/example.png" type="image/png">
    <img class="usp-pics pic1" src="/images/example.png" alt="something" title="">
</picture>
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed and in-depth answer. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @Quaren my pleasure, I felt it was a worthwhile question

Comment: @Martin God damn, dude. You rock. What a great explanation! :clap: